# How to outsource the anonymous function logic present inside subscribe() method?

Tags: angular, typescript

Consider a code block like this:

```
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    this.fetchUsers(5);
  }
  
  employees: any[] = [];
  
  fetchUsers(count: number) {
    this._http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`).subscribe(

      // need to outsource the logic below along with the function argument (count)

      (users: any) => {
        for(let i=0; i<count; i++) {
          this.employees.push(users[i])
        }
        console.log(this.employees)
      }
    );
  }
```

I tried to outsource the logic inside `subscribe()` to a separate method as below:

```
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    this.fetchUsers(5);
  }

  employees: any[] = [];
  
  fetchUsers(count: number) {
    this._http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`).subscribe(this.handleSubscribedResponse);
  }

  handleSubscribedResponse = (users: any) => {


    for(let i=0; i<count; i++) { 
      this.employees.push(users[i])
    }
    console.log(this.employees)
  }
```

The problem here is: I am unable to pass an argument from the method `fetchUsers()` containing `subscribe()` to the `handleSubscribedResponse` function scope which is being called on `subscribe()`. The `fetchUsers` function argument `count` is not passed to this scope. How can we pass the argument from above `fetchUsers` method?

I tried using `bind()` & `apply()` as below but it is of no use:

```
// bind()
this._http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`).subscribe(this.handleSubscribedResponse.bind(this, count))

// apply()
this._http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`).subscribe(this.handleSubscribedResponse.apply(this, count))
```

How can I get the argument value in outsourced on subscribe handler function?

Comment: `count` is closed over as a parameter to `fetchUsers`. If you want to use a different method as the subscriber, you have to **pass it explicitly**, e.g. `.subscribe((users) => this.handleSubscribedResponse(users, count))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A best solution will be like you should have a service having a function like this

`userService.ts`

```
fetchUsers(count: number) {
  this._http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
}
```

And in your component you can like this

`app.component.ts`

```
getUsers(userCount: number){
  this.userService.fetchUsers().subscribe((users: any[]) => this.handleSubscribedResponse(users, userCount));
}


handleSubscribedResponse = (users: any, userCount) => {
  for(let i=0; i<count; i++) { 
    this.employees.push(users[i])
  }
  console.log(this.employees)
}
```

Comment: why do you use a tap ? You could do that in the subscribe directly

Comment: you also don't have to make an arrow function when defining handleSubscribedResponse : `handleSubscribedResponse(users: any, userCount) { ... }`

Comment: Passing a callback to `subscribe` is now pretty much considered an anti-pattern. Use `pipe` and `tap`. Better, don't transform your Observable into a static array (`this.employees`), maintain the Observable chain, and use the `async` pipe to subscribe.